# How I can Use parent theme's constants in child Theme. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have Created a child theme when i load site it did not find logo image which is saved in a constant in parent theme's function file and httpd.exe memory goes upt to 1GB and did not show any error then i check apche php error log below error found.

So the question is how i can use constant defined in Parent theme function file to child theme should i need to redefine in child theme.

> [02-Jul-2015 02:53:21 UTC] PHP Warning: 
>   getimagesize(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-shahid/images/logo.png):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found  in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\my-framework\functions.php
>   on line 233

**at line 233 this is the code**

```
232: $logo = IMAGES . '/logo.png';

233: $logo_size = getimagesize( $logo );
```

Answer (score 0):

$logo = IMAGES . '/logo.png'; this is not the right way to define constant in WordPress, instead you should define it as.

```
define("THEME_LOGO", IMAGES ."/logo.png");
```

and then you can use it simply by writing THEME_LOGO, anywhere in theme scope

Comment: constant already  defined like this

define( 'IMAGES', ASSETS . '/images' );

my question is accessing logo.png using this constant works in parent theme but did not work in child theme

Comment: what error does it gives in child theme, have you checked the logo path.
May be in child theme it is searching for logo.php under child-theme folder, so in that case you need to copy your logo.png file in child-theme/images

Comment: thanks copied Image folder in child theme and it worked.

but if it did not find logo.png file why wordpress not giving error it continually loading page and httpd.exe memory usage getting high untill i end process.